# How do i automatically convert addresses into clickable links in flutter?

Tags: flutter, linkify

In Android we have https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify

and https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android:autoLink

so for example if you SMS someone an address properly formatted with city state it lets you pull up google maps when you tap on it.

How do you achieve this in flutter? The packages I find either support only url, or emamil or phone number maybe but not address.

https://pub.dev/packages/selectable_autolink_text etc

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_linkify does it assures your needs?

Comment: @Muhtar this does not support address does it? or at least the readme doe snot mention

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have an address:

```dart
var address = '1 Maritime Square, Singapore 099253';
```

You build a Google Map URL to launch:

```dart
var googleMapslocationUrl =
        "https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=$address";
```

Build an Inkwell widget for user:

```dart
InkWell(
              onTap: () => launchUrl(Uri.parse(googleMapslocationUrl)),
              child: Text(address,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                  )),
            ),
```

The launchUrl function is from the url_launcher package: https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher 
Hope this help.

Comment: i was looking for a robust prebuilt solid solution

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
...

new RichText(
      text: new TextSpan(text: 'Non touchable. ', children: [
        new TextSpan(
          text: 'Tap here.',
          recognizer: new TapGestureRecognizer()..onTap = () => print('Tap Here onTap'),
        )
      ]),
    );
```

You can use **RichText** for Linkredirects
for like Terms&condition etc.